# Angular4 reactive form validation not working

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-reactive-forms

In pic1 I have written a input tag (line: 101) and another input tag copied from other place (line: 102)
But first input tag is working but not second one, because for second input tag there is no "ng-invalid ng-touched" class in DOM (pic2). [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM7V7.png) 
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf8mm.png)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
 selector: "app-sign-up",
 templateUrl: "./sign-up.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./sign-up.component.css"]
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit(): void {
//this.Registration.va
}
Registration = new FormGroup({
  fullName: new FormControl("",[Validators.required])
 });
}
```

Comment: Make a seperate **formControl** for your second _input_

Comment: Dont include pictures no links to images as code (unless you want to show eg UI outcome). Include actual code insteed into the question.

Comment: A question you might wanna ask yourself would be, why use a duplicate `formControl` in your template?

Comment: Edit your question, add the text you show in pictures to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are using the same control for two different input. You must have separate FormControl for each form field.

Make the following changes

#### signUpComponent.component.ts

```
Registration = new FormGroup({
 fullName1: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),
 fullName2: new FormControl("",[Validators.required])
})
```

#### in your .html file

```
<input formControlName="fullName1" id="fullName1" />
<input formControlName="fullName2" id="fullName2" />
```

Comment: I tried but not working